# Открыть директорию в PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, pyside2

Нужно в *GUI* прокинуть путь к директории.

Появляется диалоговое окно, я выбираю нужную директорию, нажимаю 'Open', но ничего не происходит.

Навесил на кнопку функцию:

```
    def get_img(self):
        destDir = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,
                                                     'Open working directory',
                                                     os.getenv('HOME'),
                                                     QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)

        print(destDir)
```

Comment: у вас  `PyQt5` или `PySide2` ? и какая версия `Python` ?

Comment: Kubuntu 20.04 ,Pyqt5, PySide2 ver. 5.15.2.Пробую и в PySide2 и в PyQt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
Короче,если запускать приложение через консоль,то всё нормально работает.
А в PyCharm (у меня версия 2021.1 Community Ed.) нихрена не работает. Такие дела

Comment: Всегда запускайте приложение из консоли/терминала/CMD !!!

Answer (score 1):

Я не понимаю, почему у вас ничего не происходит

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centerWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)
        
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(QFont('Arial', 11))

        openDirButton = QPushButton("Open Directory")
        openDirButton.clicked.connect(self.browse_button)
        
        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutV.addWidget(openDirButton)
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout(centerWidget)
        layoutH.addLayout(layoutV)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)

    def browse_button(self):
        destDir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self,
            'Open working directory',
            os.getenv('HOME'),
            QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
        )

        if destDir:
            self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрал папку: <b>{}</b>".format(destDir)) 
       

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(740,480)
    w.setWindowTitle("PyQt5-QFileDialog")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Запустил ваш код. Всё точно так же. Диалоговое окно - нажимаю Open на нужной папке и ничего не происходит. Может это зависит от ОС?

Comment: @Newman какой вывод `print(destDir)`, если это установить перед `if destDir:` ?

Comment: Выводит пустую строку

Comment: @Newman  попробуйте так `destDir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Выбрать папку!")`   и так `destDir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Выбрать папку!!!")`. Каков результат `print(f'destDir = "{destDir}"')`  ?

Comment: И так и так пробовал. Не,пустая строка. Кстати, принт destDir происходит когда я закрываю диалоговое окно крестиком. А не по кнопке OPEN. По этой кнопке вообще нихрена не происходит. Короче, странная фигня

Comment: @Newman какая у вас ОС, Python, PyQt ?

Comment: Kubuntu 20.04 ,Pyqt5, PySide2 ver. 5.15.2

Comment: @Newman  `getExistingDirectory()` - статическая функция, в разных ОС 
используется по разному. 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getExistingDirectory . 

Если попадется реализация для вашей ОС, я вам напишу.

Comment: Благодарю Вас! В свою очередь , тоже попробую на другой ОС,когда получится